# Accepting all alphabetical input as valid regardless of case

Tags: python

How can I alter this code so that regardless of the case of the letters in the argument it will return True? This program just checks to see if the argument exists in any of the lists, so for example if I put `this('NORTH')`I will get the same result as `this('north')` or `this('nOrTh')` Can I use `isupper` and `islower`? Thanks in advance.

```
def scan(words):
    directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right',  'back']
    verbs = ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat']
    stop_words = ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it']
    nouns = ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']


lex = words.split()
list1 = []

for i in lex:
    if i in directions:
        list1.append(('direction', i))
    elif i in verbs:
        list1.append(('verb', i))
    elif i in stop_words:
        list1.append(('stop', i))
    elif i in nouns:
        list1.append(('noun', i))
    elif i.isdigit():
        list1.append(('number', convert_number(i)))
    else:
        list1.append(('error', i))
return list1 

def convert_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)

    except ValueError:
        return None

this = scan('NORTH')
print this
```

Comment: Looks like you might have screwed up your indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to make your source text all lowercase:

```
lex = words.lower().split()
```

Comment: I was thinking this as well, I don't know I jsut felt like it would be cheating if I did it this way haha.

Comment: There is no such thing as cheating in programming ;)

Comment: Haha I guess you're right, there's another way I'd like to do this. What if I didn't want to convert the string to lowercase? I wanted the program to recognize `north` and `NORTH` as the same. So if I wanted to `print` it it would display exactly what the user inputted?

Comment: Nvm figured it out, I just check if `i.lower()` is in any of the dictionaries. If it is then I `append` `i` to the new dictionary `list1`

Answer (score 1):

Yup.

```
a = "North"
b = "NORTH" == a.upper()
print b
#True.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a simple string match with case ignore this is how it can be done -

```
>>> s="NORTH"
>>> d="noRtH"
>>> s.lower() == d.lower()
True
```